# How to highlight ListBox Items matching a certain condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have 2 ListBoxes defined thus:

```
        <ListBox Name="aggregatesListBox" SelectionChanged="aggregatesList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Amount}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AccountId}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox Name="postingsListBox" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PostingId}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Amount}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CreatedDate}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AccountId}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I want all items in the postings list to be highlighted (in some way, preferably background colour) if they share the same Account Id as the currently selected aggregated item.

What are my options?

On the advice given I have modified as follows

```
       <ListBox Name="postingsListBox" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <local:IdToBrushConverter x:Key="IdToBrushConverter" />
                        </StackPanel.Resources>

                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IdToBrushConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="aggregatesListBox" Path="SelectedItem.AccountId"/>
                                <Binding Path="AccountId"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </StackPanel.Background>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PostingId}"  /> 
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Amount}"     />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CreatedDate}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AccountId}"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"       />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and

```
    public class IdToBrushConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Color colour;

        if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || ((int)values[0] != (int)values[1]))
            colour = System.Windows.Media.Colors.White;
        else
            colour = System.Windows.Media.Colors.CornflowerBlue;

        return new SolidColorBrush(colour);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("");
    }
}
```

An attribute on the Window is required so that the brush converter can be located

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAccountingThing"
```

I also changed the behind the scenes logic to use a list of Objects as the `ItemsSource` of each of the 2 Listboxes rather than the `DataRowView` I had previously.

Sorted - Thanks!

Comment: Use a MultiBinding to bind the StackPanel's Background property to the AccountId of the current item and that of the SelectedItem of the other ListBox. A multi-value converter would check both values for equality and return an appropriate Brush.

Comment: @clemens I have taken your advice (I think) but am still missing something

Comment: As said (and in contrast to the answer), I would directly bind the `AccountId` properties, meaning that the Paths in the MultiBinding would be `SelectedItem.AccountId` and `AccountId`.

Comment: Which I think is the problem I had with my own attempts in the first place.  Rightly or wrongly the `ItemsSource` of the 2 ListBoxes is a `DataTable.DefaultView` an I cannot see how I should bind to those.

Comment: What type are the objects received by the value parameter?

Comment: @bruno `DataRowView` (I take it you mean in the converter)

Comment: you have to find a way to pass both id's to compare then, maybe you should bind your ItemsSource with a collection of the type that hold the AccountID property.

Comment: @bruno the converter is working and producing the correct results, but the stackpanel is not changing its background

Comment: I now what the problem is, you have to return a Brush color instead a SystemColor, the background property only accept a Brush color -> error generated on output::::: "Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='ControlDarkDarkColor' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')"

Comment: if you open your output window you'll be able to see the error

Comment: I have it working now - I think that has been the issue all along.  I will write up later what I did because I used parts of your answer and also drew on Clemens' comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a multibinding with a converter, here's an example.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="list1"
             ItemsSource="{Binding List1}">
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox x:Name="list2"
             ItemsSource="{Binding List2}"
             Grid.Column="2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}">
                        <TextBlock.Background>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                                <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="list1"/>
                                <Binding Path="."/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Background>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

On my silly example, I used the MultiBiding to be able to pass more than one parameter to the Converter, which is the selectedItem on the list1 and the currentItem that ListBox2 is applying the Template, next, I used the converter to compare the received values:

**Converter:**

```
public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var selectedValueList1 = values[0];
        var currentItemList2 = values[1];

        if(selectedValueList1 == null) // Listbox 1 has no selected Item
            return Brushes.Black;

        if (selectedValueList1 == currentItemList2)
            return Brushes.Red;

        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And of course, you have to elaborate better the test on your converter, in my example I just pass two strings to be compared.

And that is it, it works like expected.

[image]

Comment: This has been quite helpful but does not take account of the existence of multiple `TextBox` items under one Item.

Comment: You have to pass on the second biding the "AccountId" instead the own item, and in the first binding you should pass the "AccountId" of the selected item. My example is completely different than yours, you should pass to the converter both ID's in order to compare then.